# Is 'Night an acceptable informal variant of "Good Night"?

Tags: formality, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

The spoken use of "night" as an informal, familiar version of "good night" (wishing one a restful sleep) is common, but I'm not sure what the proper written equivalent is - if there is one. I have always used **'Night** with an apostrophe, usually capitalized:

> **'Night**, Caroline!

Is any form of "night" for "good night" (with or without an apostrophe) correct as used in my example? I read a lot of Walt Kelly growing up so that may be why I use it.

I don't see a reason to use the apostrophe, as I'm not using "G'Night", with or without capitalization.

Are there different rules when conveying informal speech in writing?

Comment: I might use the apostrophe to make it clear the person is saying *'Night* rather than, for whatever reason  *Night*.

Comment: Yes, it's an acceptable variant. So is *Nite*, at least on email.

Comment: You may be interested to know that Marsha Norman wrote a very successful play titled [**'night Mother**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'night,_Mother) in 1982.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly *informal* but you could appeal to perceived gradations of formality along the progression from `Good night.` to `G'night.` (contraction) to simply, `Night.` (elide the 'g' sound). The final case being in the same form as saying `Later.` for `See you later.`, if one is acceptable, the other should be as well.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use an apostrophe, but it's not necessary. [OED](http://oed.com) lists both *night* and *'night*:

> ‘Good-night. I'm goin' to roost.’ ‘Night, Dave.’
>   <sub>(1912) [Being the Story of What Happened When Buck Peters, Hopalong Cassidy, and Their Bar-20 Associates Went to Montana](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/42800/42800-8.txt)</sub>

> ‘'Night.’ ‘'Night.’ It was cold in the bedroom.
>   <sub>(1992) [Come the Executioner](https://books.google.com/books/about/Come_the_Executioner.html?id=yLkfAAAACAAJ)</sub>

---

And [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nite) lists both *nite* and *'nite*. While these forms are **really** informal, you can sometimes find them in books, such as [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=iAKdiOanoWUC&pg=PA359&dq=%22nite+all%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp-LTr-rHTAhVIMSYKHZuLC9QQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%22nite%20all%22&f=false) or [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=JZ2DpjcJC04C&pg=PT151&dq=%22nite+love%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLx9bj-7HTAhVHMyYKHTSgC1cQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=%22nite%20love%22&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the context, as others have alluded to.  "Good night, sweetheart", he said, looking deeply into her eyes, sounds much better than "night, y'all", he said to the family. Or, using it twice, as in "night, night, son" as his boy wended his weary way to bed. So, yes, I think context is the determinant.